# Centering text in a listview Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a dynamic listView in Jquery mobile but having problems centering it. I created my own css file and tried putting the css in my HTML doc but it seems not to take any notice of the css.

**Here is the CSS**

```
#myList .ui-btn-inner {
text-align: center;
}
```

**Here is the listView**

```
<div data-role="mainPage" data-theme="a">

<div data-role="header">

</div>

<div style="width:500px;height:100px;background-color:white;"></div>

<div data-role="content">
 <ul data-role="listview" id="fixturesList">

    </ul>
 </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

```
   '<li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="b">\ ' + oldDate + '\ </li><li id="myList" data-icon="false"><a href="javascript:void(0)'
    + '" onclick="goToMatchDetailPage(\''
    + match.Home +'\')">' 
    + match.Home + '\ v \ ' + match.Away 
    + '</a></li>';
```

The second piece of the code is in js.

Comment: what is ui-btn-inner?

Comment: jQuery mobile will generate that on buttons. So it can be styled the way they want. So this is the base HTML not the OUTPUT html which will be edited by jQuery mobile.

Comment: to be honest i thought you have to put that in to override the jquery default for the list

Comment: Some of the listview text are quite long so could it be that what stopping it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this CSS (must come after jQM CSS files are loaded).

Assuming you have a UL:

```
<ul id="theList" data-role="listview">
```

Use its ID to limit the scope of the CSS to this list:

```
#theList li a, #theList li.ui-li-divider {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

If you don't need the divider centered, remove the part after the comma

> jQM 1.4 **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/WZ3qk/3/)**
>
> jQM 1.3 **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/WZ3qk/2/)**

Comment: sometimes you need the !important to make sure of the override specificity. jQM add lots of CSS rules at different levels of specificity, so you sometimes end up fighting these rules...

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

Just added a centering class to the list generator template

css

```
.centered{text-align:center;}
```

js

```
'<li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="b">\ ' + oldDate + '\ </li><li id="myList" 
class="centered" data-icon="false"><a href="javascript:void(0)'
+ '" onclick="goToMatchDetailPage(\''
+ match.Home +'\')">' 
+ match.Home + '\ v \ ' + match.Away 
+ '</a></li>';
```

Comment: Didn't even move. it's like it is not recognizing my style sheet.

Comment: Does this seem right to you.    <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="list.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: try putting the link to list.css below jquery...css. Also it might help to put a few css properties in the header inside <style></style> and see if that works.

Comment: I tried that but still looks like no response at all

Comment: what about adding style="text-align:center;" to the li in the list generator?

Comment: It not doing anything at all. The css file either on it own or in the HTML doesn't effect the list